# How to get sorted list based on unsorted list not modifing unsorted

Tags: java, list, sorting

Suppose I have some some list

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 1, 4);
```

How can I get list

```
List<Integer> list2
```

that contains exactly the same values as list1 but is sorted? 
And the important thing is I can't modify list1

Comment: This can be found with google: check out Collections.sort(...)

Comment: `list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);`, then sort `list2`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot that I can pass list to the constructor of the ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a copy of the original list and then perform Collections.sort()

Answer (score -1):

You can first copy list1 to list2

```
List<Integer> list2 = list1;
```

then sort the new object

```
Collections.sort(list2);
```

This will leave the original object untouched.

Comment: This will not leave the original object untouched, because in the line `List<Integer> list2 = list1;` you have only copied a *reference* to the object.